# Holy Grail IE8 Problem with Table (style="width: 1000%")

Tags: language-agnostic

I am using a home page based upon the Three-Column Holy Grail layout by Matthew James Taylor.  The layout works just fine in all browers except, surprise, IE8.  My center column, where the my main data lives contains a table tag like:

```
<table style="width: 100%">...
```

The result is not what was expected.  I am using the version where the width of the left and right columns are`defined as fixed pixel valuse.  I have not tried the percentage version yet.

Does anyone have any suggestions.  I really like Taylor's design.

Thanks,

Danny

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the CSS you're using to fix the layout in IE6 and IE7 aren't causing the issues with IE8.

Your best bet is to re-write any CSS hacks (fixes) using seperate stylesheets using IE Conditional Comments to load them specifically for IE7 and IE6 seperately.